# Rails 3 path parameters not part of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to upgrade a Rails 2 app to Rails 3, and I'm really having problems with a route. Here's what I have in the routes.rb file

```
get 'profile/:login' => 'account#profile', :as => :profile
```

When I go to *http://localhost:3000/profile/MyUsername*, it does not correctly add :login to the params hash. See here:

```
Started GET "/profile/MyUsername?foo=bar" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Mar 20 21:39:03 -0400 2012
  Processing by AccountController#profile as HTML
  Parameters: {"foo"=>"bar"}
```

For some reason, :login is not part of the regular params. On a hunch, I inspected the *request.env* and found this:

```
action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:action=>"profile", :controller=>"account", :login=>"MyUsername"}
```

I'm totally stumped at this point. Am I missing something? Where should I look next to figure out what is going on here?

**Update**

I started playing with removing gems and this magically worked. I just commented out gems from the Gemfile until I got the absolute minimal set needed to load the homepage. At that point, the params were exactly as expected. Then I added gems back a few at a time in order to find the cause. I added everything back and...it works now. Crazy, but whatever it takes, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you mixed the syntax for 'match' with 'get'. Please try:

```
match 'profile/:login' => 'account#profile', :as => :profile, :via => :get
```

Or

```
get 'profile/:login', :to => 'account#profile', :as => :profile
```

in your config/routes.rb

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried mixing and matching 'get' and 'match' and the various options.

Comment: Can you add to the question the output of rake routes? Probably you have checked but i'm thinking in some route conflict.

Comment: I'm a little paranoid (and embarrassed) about posting the entire routes output. It's really ugly, especially considering it was auto-converted from Rails 2 to Rails 3. I can say with confidence though that the only route that starts with "profile" is the route I want. And, from the log I can tell that it's going to the correct action, just not passing :login as a params element.

Comment: i understand, it's weird, have you tried a diffent param name? not login (maybe conflicting with some code of internals i guess)

Comment: Yeah, I tried changing the param (login) to something else (like foo) and also changing the route (profile) to something else (like myaccount). Neither approach seemed to make a difference. I'll see if other routes have similar issues with path parameters

Comment: What rails 3 version are you using, I believe the old route styles still work, have you tried just using your old routes?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to use URL params I always use resource(s) when defining the route. That is convention with Rails 3.x so you can try it.

```
  resources :accounts , :exclude => :all do
    member do
      get  :profile
    end
  end
```

This should help or any other way of defining resource URL.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
match 'profile(/:login)' => "account#profile", :as => :profile
```

If it does not, there may be something else in your routes file that conflicts. Make sure any `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` (or similar "match everything" routes) are at the very bottom of your routes file.